# Jenkins iOS build - FATAL: Log statements out of sync: current test case was null

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, jenkins, xctest

I have a jenkins build server that is configured to build my iOS project. Recently the build times have greatly increased, going from around 2 min/build to 10 min/build. While watching the console output, I can see that the build keeps getting hung up after the error message:

```
FATAL: Log statements out of sync: current test case was null
```

It takes probably a minute for the build to continue running. These messages seem to be occurring after a suit of test cases are run (XCTest framework).

Has anyone seen this console log before? Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I cant seem to find much information online.

My Jenkins Xcode plugin is version 1.4.9, and JUnit plugin is 1.9.

Comment: This is a duplicate to a question asked here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38662709/jenkins-ios-build-fatal-log-statements-out-of-sync-current-test-case-was-nul/50225522?noredirect=1#comment87470009_50225522